# Стилевое оформление кода на python, где читать?

Tags: python

Знакомый порекомендовал почитать про стилевое оформление подскажите сайты или ресурсы на данную тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте pep-8:
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html,
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - Вот русский и официальный источник.

Answer (score 2):

Это содержится в [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) "Style Guide for Python Code".

*PS. PEP - Python Enhancement Proposals, заявки на улучшение языка.*